# Percentile ranking with multiple metrics

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm looking to rank a number of records (ASX stocks) using a number of metrics using percentile ranking. I've used the following website to calculate the percentile rank, which works fine for me.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/PERCENT_RANK/141532/

Let's say for example, I want to rank them by highest earnings, lowest debt-to-equity ratio for now (I'll be ranking with probably more than 5 metrics). Let's say I want the highest earnings to have a higher importance of say 20%

Do I need to calculate the percentile ranking of each/metric seperately and then in this combine the two percentages and apply the 20% factor?

So for example:
ABC
Earnings percentile: 90% (one of the highest earners)
Debt percentile: 10% (Has a high level of debt)

Then combine the 90% with the 10% to get an overall ranking?

```
; WITH CTE

AS
(
select
    e.SecurityCode,
    e.Earning,
    e.TotalDebtToEquity,
    rk1 = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY e.Earning),
    rk2 = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY e.TotalDebtToEquity),
    NR = COUNT(*) OVER ()
from Earning e 


SELECT
    SecurityCode,
    Earning,
    TotalDebtToEquity,
    PercentileEarningRank = ROUND((1.0*(rk1 - 1)/(nr-1))*100.00, 2),
    TotalDebtToEquity = ROUND((1.0*(rk2 - 1)/(nr-1))*100.00, 2)
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Please show some concrete data to back up your question.  And also show the output you expect from that data.

Comment: I don't know what the exact output is as I'm working with a large amount of data and this is sort of a trial and error task atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a weighted average. If all the variables (say there are 5 called a,b,c,d and e) have the same importance, you would just compute:

```
out = (a+b+c+d+e)/5;
```

but if you wanted a to be 20% more important then everything else, you would compute

```
out = (1.2*a+b+c+d+e)/5.2;
```

note the divisor has to change in order to bring the result back into the 0-100 range (basically the divisor is the sum of the individual coefficents, in this case 1.2+1+1+1+1=5.2).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. So I'll just need to use the weighted average to combine the various metrics to get the final result